# C++ Boost Asio - UDP - How to send a file in 512 bytes blocks?

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio

I'm implementing a TFTP server.
I have to send a file to the client, and as 512 bytes blocks.
My knowledge from UDP networking and Boost::Asio are very low...

I'm based on the UDP async echo server example.
There's no problem to get the client request, and now I have to send him the file as blocks.

How would you do that ?

Thanks

EDIT:

I'm trying to read and extract the first block, I'm doing this way:

```
if (ok && opCode == 1) // RRQ TFTP Request
{
    char * file_buffer = new char[512];
    std::ifstream file (fileName, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        file.read(file_buffer, 512);
    }
}
```

It's temporary code, of course, I have to understand how that's work, reading the file and sending the blocks. Is it OK this way (presuming the file is bigger as 512 bytes) ?

Comment: What's the question? How to chop a file into blocks? How to send data over UDP? How to cope with retransmissions? How to error check and correct?

Comment: Well, at the moment I'm trying to chop the file into blocks and send them over UDP.

Comment: So what is your problem *exactly*? Do you have code that's failing, if so post it.

Comment: Sorry Joe, my first time on stack overflow. I add some info on my forum thread. I'm a little confused about how to "split" the file.